# Getting video id "Live Stream" from Youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm having trouble getting the video ID, which is live, using YouTube API v3. I use the **"playlists"** query to get the current videos from the channel, all right, but there is no live broadcast in this data. The problem can be solved by applying the query **"search"**, but it weighs 100 quotas, and this is not suitable for me. Does anyone know a possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, here is my code on python.

```
from lxml import html
import requests 

page = requests.get(f"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel={channel_id}")
    if page.status_code == 200:
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        links = tree.xpath('//link[@rel="canonical"]')
        if links:
            id = links[0].attrib['href'].split("watch?v=")[1]
```